# Xcode Exception Stops at top of Stack

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Dears,

Since I installed XCode 8 I noticed something that is somehow annoying to me.

Whenever there is an exception in the code, XCode does not point me to the line that caused this exception, instead, it points me to the top of the thread.

For example, this happens

[image: As you can see it automatically pointed me to the top of stack in thread 9]

What I always expecting is to point me to the class I have developed like this:

[image: This is whats expected, so I would know immediately where is the problem]

Yes, I know that I can switch every time manually, but this is wasting time. It would be helpfull if someone tells me if there is a setting that would make Xcode point to the development files instead of this weird file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you add an Exception Breakpoint, Xcode will break when the exception is thrown, which sounds like what you want (and is pretty useful).

Comment: Thanks, Ted, But this is not the case I am asking about. Breakpoints are working. What's not working properly is pointing on lines with problems when I am not expecting the exception

Comment: I just made a test project with this line in  -`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   NSLog(@"%@", [[NSArray array] objectAtIndex:1]);` -- and with no breakpoints, it stops in main(). If I add an Exception Breakpoint (break on any exception), the debugger stops on this line, where the exception is thrown.

Comment: So I guess something wrong in my preferences. I don't have an idea why this is happening.